# WPF Datagrid not losing focus when a nested item is clicked

Tags: wpf, datagrid, nested, focus, edit

I have a datagrid with a template column that nests another datagrid. When I edit a person's name on the main datagrid and then double click to edit a nested item, the main one doesn't lose focus so that the cell remains in editing mode.

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK725.png).

I deal with it by registering GotFocus event for the nested datagrid, finding parent datagrid in visual tree using a custom FindAncestor function and invoking CancelEdit() on the main datagrid.

```
private void DataGridItem_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dg =(DataGrid)FindAncestor((DependencyObject)sender, typeof(DataGrid), 2);
            dg.CancelEdit();
        }
```

That is rather an overkill. Is there a different, maybe a more MVVM-esque way to tackle this issue?

Below is the full code of this simplified example.

XAML

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding DataCollectionSelectedItem}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  CanUserAddRows="false" >
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="2*" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item/Price" Width="3*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridItem" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ItemsSelectedItem}"
                                      GotFocus="DataGridItem_GotFocus"
                                      Background="Transparent"
                                      HeadersVisibility="None"
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                      CanUserAddRows="false" >
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemName}" Width="*"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="50"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace datagrid_focus
{
    public class Item : NotifyObject
    {
        private string _itemName;
        public string ItemName
        {
            get { return _itemName; }
            set { _itemName = value; OnPropertyChanged("ItemName"); }
        }
        private double _price;
        public double Price
        {
            get { return _price; }
            set { _price = value; OnPropertyChanged("Price"); }
        }
    }

    public class Person : NotifyObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }
        public double Total
        {
            get { return Items.Sum(i => i.Price); }
            set { OnPropertyChanged("Total"); }
        }
    }

    public abstract class NotifyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : NotifyObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> DataCollection { get; set; }
        public Person DataCollectionSelectedItem { get; set; }
        public Item ItemsSelectedItem { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>
            {
                new Person {Name = "Siegmund Freud", Items = new ObservableCollection<Item> {
                        new Item { ItemName = "Phone", Price = 220 },
                        new Item { ItemName = "Tablet", Price = 350 },
                    } },
                new Person {Name = "Karl Popper", Items = new ObservableCollection<Item> {
                        new Item { ItemName = "Teddy Bear Deluxe", Price = 2200 },
                        new Item { ItemName = "Pokemon", Price = 100 }
                    }}
            };
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }

        public DependencyObject FindAncestor(DependencyObject current, Type type, int levels)
        {
            int currentLevel = 0;
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.GetType() == type)
                {
                    currentLevel++;
                    if (currentLevel == levels)
                    {
                        return current;
                    }
                }
                current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
            };
            return null;
        }

        private void DataGridItem_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dg =(DataGrid)FindAncestor((DependencyObject)sender, typeof(DataGrid), 2);
            //dg.CancelEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic, so you start to edit the (first grid) cell and as you editing the second grid, which is the editing of the first, you want to cancel the editing of the first grid. If so, the editing of second grid must be also canceled. You can try to do, what you want through binding of Cell.IsEditing to your view model(two properties for each grid), but I find this logic is not clear.

Comment: I want that both parent and child datagrids be editing one cell at a time.

Comment: "..double click to edit a nested item, the main one doesn't lose focus so that the cell remains in editing mode". I have understood this as that you want, that first grid cell does not remain in editing mode.